# weird spring usage in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

I was studying the internals of the Spring Security and I found the following two methods in the `WebSecurityConfiguration`:

```
    public void setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(
        ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor,
        @Value("#{@autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers()}") List<SecurityConfigurer<Filter, WebSecurity>> webSecurityConfigurers)
        throws Exception {
          ...
        }
```

and

```
    @Bean
public AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents(
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
          ...
        }
```

as I understand `{@autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers()}`, in the first method, calls the method `autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents`. But that method has a parameter `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory`. How does this parameter is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the [EL-expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), it actually calls `getWebSecurityConfigurers` from the bean `autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents`.

The method `AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)` is the one creating the bean `autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents`

Comment: Thx, that is a perfect answer. Can you please also tell, how ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory is passed for creation of the autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents bean? I don't see any autowired annotation.

Comment: I don't know, I assume spring resolves the argument because the `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` is some spring IOC internal. Maybe you could ask that as a new question